# How to show numeric keyboard in android 5.0 (lollipop)

Tags: javascript, html, webview, android-5.0-lollipop

Using Moto G, which is supposedly running stock Android 5.0, browser and webview are showing full keyboard when an input (type=number) is in focus.

This is a different behavior from Android 4.x which used to show a numeric keyboard.

Is there a workaround that tricks Android into showing numeric keyboard?

Here is my markup:

```
<input type="number" id="number1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the type to `tel` if you want the phone-like keyboard

```
<input type="tel" id="number1">
```

Iv'e used this with `ionic framework` [on this project](https://github.com/Jossef/amigos/blob/master/www/src/login/login-view.html) and can confirm it on nexus 5 with android 5.1

Comment: type=tel does not show numeric keyboard in 5.0.  Do you know if type=number shows the numeric keyboard in 5.1?